# Facebook Connect on mobile site expanding the page width

Tags: facebook

Facebook's mobile examples use the script:  http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js.  This script adds to the div fb-root.  My mobile site is 320px wide and I use the viewport meta setting.  Including Facebook's script causes a big extra space on the right side of the actual content because it's settings it's contents to 575px wide.  I tried including code to replace the 575px with 320px ("#fb-root").val().replace("575px","320px"); but that hasn't helped -- maybe I'm doing it wrong (using jQuery).

Anyone know how to restrict this to 320px?

Update:
Found a bug a report on this with two work-arounds:

1. Set status to false in the FB.init.  I can verify that this does fix the problem for me, but breaks the ability for users to login.
2. Move `<div id="fb-root"></div>` directly under `<body>`.  This didn't work for me.

Source:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18528

Answer (score 5):

I used the following css style rule to beat this 575px #fb-root width problem:

```
#fb-root > div { left:-575px !important; }
```

That works because, if you locate the #fb-root node in, say, Firebug's HTML tree-viewer, you'll find that it contains a child div that is styled as follows:

```
position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0pt; width: 0pt;
```

Answer (score 1):

i just set this in the css by default

```
#fb-root{display:none}
```

and when i need to use the FB dialogs(when calling FB.ui), i do this:

```
$('#fb-root').show();
```

and in the callback of the FB.ui, i do this

```
$('#fb-root').hide();
```

so here is an example:

```
var inviteFriend = function (msg) {
    $('#fb-root').show();
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: msg
    }, function (response) {
        $('#fb-root').hide();
        console.log('sendRequest response: ', response);
    });
},
```

this works for me, and i have tested on some devices.

Comment: seems unnecessarily complicated... adding a negative 'left' position to the fb-root's nested div's seems easier.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided seems to only replace the value in the code, which has, by that point, already fired. You might try to setting the width with [jquery's .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method on fb-root. Make sure this is fired after the fb js sdk is included, or put into the callback method if loading asynchronously.

Comment: I ended up finding a bug on this a minute ago: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18528.  There were two work-arounds for it.

Comment: The first workaround breaks the ability to login to facebook, which won't work for me and the second workaround doesn't fix the problem.  The iframe facebook adds has a fixed width of 575px.  I'm trying to figure out how I change that.  So far I haven't had any luck getting the iframe (the id and name change every time so I can't use those).

Answer (score 0):

Or just wrap it in another div, set its height and width, and the put overflow:hidden;